# Windows 7 Custom Environment Variable Disappears

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, ms-dos

I am trying to set a custom environment variable in Windows 7, which needs to be done programmatically as it must be set on multiple computers.

I have been testing one a single machine, but When I create it programmatically, it exists for that session (i.e. in DOS when the command window is open, or in Powershell when the ISE is open) - however, when I close the session the variable disappears?

How do I make it permanent?

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 3):

**for users**
wmic environment  create name='test', variablevalue='air',username='domain\username'

**for computer**
wmic environment  create name='test', variablevalue='air',username='system'

can work remotely by using the /node: paramter

**maybe overkill but**

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/06/03/hey-scripting-guy-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-read-a-text-file-and-update-an-environment-variable-on-remote-computers.aspx

Comment: As tony has suggested, add it to the user or system environment variables in the advanced system properties.

Comment: Sorry - didn't make it clear in the question: This needs to be done programatically as I need to roll out the variable to multiple laptops.

Comment: @ben see the updated answer for more details

Comment: use @shay's method!

Answer (score 1):

The basic syntax is:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(<name>,<value>,<EnvironmentVariableTarget>)
```

This will create a new permanant env variable for the logged on user:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("NewVar","NewValue","User")
```

And this one for the system:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("NewVar","NewValue","Machine")
```

Comment: This needs a reboot to become "visible", right? Is there a way for it to become available instantly?

Comment: Basically yes, if you want it to be visible to a certain application then just restart that app.